# i want to create this type of custom expansion tile that allows one panel to be open at a time

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 onExpansionChanged: (value){
                                                        if(value) {
                                                          setState((){
                                                            selected = index;
                                                          });
                                                        }
                                                        else{
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            selected = -1;
                                                          });
                                                        }
                                                      },
```

i am building a app in home page i want to dislay this list i want to create this type of custom expansion tile that allows one panel to be open at a time , i implement expansion tile but its not work perfect according to my need

[image: i am building a app in home page i want to dislay this list i want to create this type of custom expansion tile that allows one panel to be open at a time , i implement expansion tile but its not work perfect according to my need]

Comment: please include your code

Comment: please share your code also

Comment: please share your whole code

Comment: Try [ExpansionPanelList.radio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.radio.html).